# How do I use imagemagick to convert HEIC to JPG and preserve quality?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I'd like to batch convert `.heic` images (e.g. iPhone photograph) to `.jpg` files with imagemagick, with the goal of retaining as much of the quality from the original image as possible.  To be clear, the resulting output size is not a concern.

I've been using

```
magick input.heic -quality 100% output.jpg
```

Is it possible to do better?

Comment: Quality 100% in JPEG isn't any better than quality 95% and takes a lot more space. And to be realistic, since we are talking about overprocessed pictures from a smartphone, 85% should be enough...

Comment: @xenoid Oh I'm not overly attached to the `-quality` parameter, it's just what I've been using up until now.  If you are aware of any better ways of preserving quality without ballooning the file size, please feel free to share :)

Comment: At 85-90% yoyu  already preserving the "quality". For what it's worth, on expensive DLSRs, the JPEG quality is around 97%.

Comment: Why not stick with the efficient HEIC file you already have? Or make JPEGs as you are and use them, but archive the HEICs to a separate disk (cheap as chips nowadays) and you can always refer back if you really, really need the extra quality later.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I would if I could, but unfortunately "high quality" jpgs are a hard requirement for the functionality I'm working on

Comment: @MarkSetchell One reason for wanting to avoid HEIC is that it's still less widely supported than JPEG. For example, to preview these files in Windows 10 File Explorer/open them in the Photos app, I would need to purchase a 0,99€ "extension" from Microsoft, in their App Store. :-/

Comment: HEIC is lossless, but JPG is a lossy compression even at 100% quality. The -quality parameter is for writing the output not reading the input. So it only affects the output JPG. Bottom line, you will always lose quality when writing to JPG whether you start with HEIC or PNG or any lossless format input.

Comment: @fmw42 HEIC is a higher quality than JPEG but it is a compressed format (using HEVC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding), not a lossless format.

Answer (score 18):

You can batch convert HEIC to jpg with the following, but you'll lose quality:

```
mogrify -format jpg *.HEIC
```

Comment: I think you need the `magick` command before `mogrify`, is that right? So it's `magick mogrify ...`.

Comment: usually one sets up one's path to include all the commands in the imagemagic `bin` directory, so you can just call `mogrify` directly, as that should be a command in that bin directory

Comment: Oh I see. Perhaps that might be the case on Mac/Linux, but the official Windows binary I downloaded a couple of days ago is just a single `magick.exe`, which requires you to enter that first before any of the sub-utils. Hence your answer didn’t work for me initially.

Comment: ah yeah, the Windows port may require some additional care :)

Answer (score 6):

No, its not possible to do better per ImageMagick's website for [`-quality` switch](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality). In '[Supported Image Formats](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported)' section scroll to JPEG as maybe there are other options that can be sure to limit any other quality changes inherit to converting.

[Apparently HEIC & JPEG are both lossy compression image types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression#Methods). [According to Adobe](https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/file-types/image/comparison/heic-vs-jpeg.html) editing JPEG numerous times could slowly erode its quality whereas HEIC doesn't do that.

> Because JPEG is a lossy file format, the files lose data each time you
> edit and resave an image. This means the quality of a file can degrade
> over time as you edit and re-edit, destroying more data each time.
>
> HEICs, while also a lossy file format, tend to retain better image
> quality over time. They also store editing information, so even once
> you’ve saved edits to an image, you can reverse them in the future.

[This quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-quality-loss-when-converting-from-HEIC-files-to-JPEG-files-using-the-Internets-web-based-options-and-connecting-to-that-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-them-or-display-files-to-Microsoft) says you may lose colors:

> HEIF is also 16 bit colour depth as opposed to JPEGs 8 bit colour depth
> I can't quickly find an official industry specification page confirming that. HEIC can contain different files types inside it making it confusing.

Comment: Just a note: the original poster wants to output JPG images. The source format is HEIC but the output should be JPG. So the quote you provided from the website is not really relevant.

Comment: @SimonEast thank you for pointing out my glaring oversight. I changed my answer significantly. Over 2yr & no one mentioned & still upvoted, I guess we're all skimming or wanting answers that may not be true.